# Объявление переменной. Как правильно сделать?

Tags: javascript, переменные

Всем привет! Возникло у меня непонимание по поводу как это все работает. Смотрел этот видеоурок https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-_DkOqZPNo&feature=youtu.be.

Суть задачи следующая:  Имеется блок куда надо поочередно вписать элементы массива через каждые 1 секунду. И надо сделать так чтобы все это повторялось.

Для того чтобы понять суть происходящего. Пишу точно также как и автор видео. Но тут возникает ошибка. Хотя на видео весь данный код рабоатет.

Блок, куда я хочу записать элементы массива:

```
    <div id="elem"></div>
```

Код JS файла, который на видеоуроке и который работает, но не работает у меня.

```
    var texts = ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3'];
    var elem = document.querySelector('#elem');

    var i = 0;
    window.setInterval(function() {
            elem.innerHTML = texts[i];
            i++;
            if (i === texts.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
    }, 1000);
```

Код JS файла, который работает у меня.

```
    var texts = ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3'];

    var i = 0;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        var elem = document.querySelector('#elem');
            elem.innerHTML = texts[i];
            i++;
            if (i === texts.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
    }, 1000);
```

Сам код понятен, что он делает. Непонятно почему не правильно работает объявление переменной elem. Вопрос наверно легкий, но прошу помогите, если кто нибудь знает в чем тут дело.

Comment: скопировал "код, который работает на видео, но не работает у меня" - всё работает так, как и должно

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что значит "не работает". Выводится какая-то ошибка? У меня оба примера работают.

Comment: Дело скорее всего в том, что в момент загрузки документа `#elem` еще не существует. Вам нужно использовать события `DOMContentLoaded` или перенести ваш скрипт в конец html. Раз это не показывается в видеоуроке - значит это плохой видеоурок.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли, я и забыл про то что скрипт может обрабатываться вначале и не загружать сперва само дерево.